# Making hover for back to back-bar chart in R

Tags: r

## Sample table

Animals <- read.table(
               header=TRUE, text='Options_ord        Reason Gender Count
               1  No     Genuine           M    24
               2  Yes    Genuine           F   -16
               3  No    Misclassified      M    85
               4  No    Misclassified      F    41
               5  Yes    Taxonomic         F    -2 
               6  Yes    Taxonomic         M     7
               7  No     Unclear           F   -41
               8  Yes    Unclear           M   117' )

#Trying to make back to back bar chart in R

```
>     trace_graph3<- ggplot(Animals, aes(x = (Animals$Options_ord), y = 
          Animals$Count, fill = Gender)) +
          geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
          facet_share(~Gender, dir = "h", scales = "free", reverse_num = 
           TRUE) + theme_bw(base_size = 9.5)+
          coord_flip() +
           theme_minimal()
```

## Printing the graph

> print(trace_graph3 + labs(y="in %", x = ""))

**For the above graph I want to create a hover. I tried ggplotly but unfortunately it throws me an error of attempt to apply non function in R**

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest to install and use plotly . all you need is to wrap your normal ggplot with plotly. Plotly is very powerful yet simple when it comes to interactivity.

```
install.packages('plotly')
library(plotly)

ggplotly(trace_graph3)
```

Comment: All ready tried this. Doesn't work , I also have mentioned the error I get after doing plotly